# Can I change color bitmap, 2 color to 1 color?

Tags: vb.net

Can I change the color, more than one color at a time in vb net???

2 color to 1 color

green to magenta and blue to magenta

[images A convert color to images B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWlAA.png)

Comment: [**How to: Use a Color Remap Table**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b4dc1kz(v=vs.110).aspx) and: [**`ImageAttributes.SetRemapTable()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h9aaxdk(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: it's just to change one color?,  how if the change over from two or more colors, with the same time?

Comment: `SetRemapTable` takes _**an array**_ of `ColorMap`s.

Comment: ok Thank u  :D         
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

            myColorMap(i) = New ColorMap
            myColorMap(i).OldColor = Color.FromName(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString)
            myColorMap(i).NewColor = Color.Black
            Console.WriteLine(ListBox1.Items(i))
 

        Next